# How to get products order by UPDATED_AT in Woocommerce REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-rest-api

In Woocommerce REST API v3 Docs, only certain fields are orderable - `date  /id / include / title / slug`.

[image]

If I set **`orderby=date`**, it is sorted by **`date_created`**.

I'd like to order by **`date_modified`**.

Is there a way I can get products in custom order not defined in the API?

```
?order=desc&filter[orderby]=date_modified
```

Is this kind of parameter still acceptable for v3?

It's not working for me.

Or I see this parameter.

[image]

Is this can be used for custom sort? In that case, how can it be used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Apparently it isn't supported in current version of woo-commerce api

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get products or orders by the date_modified stamp via the REST API. What I ended up doing for products and orders was create an extension using a custom endpoint and use the 'post_type' which does allow for sorting by 'date_modified_after'. This returns the order id's which you will then need to make an additional request back to the REST api with the list of id's

Answer (score 0):

```
   $params['modified_after']  = array(
        'description'       => __( 'Limit response to resources modified after a given ISO8601 compliant date.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'              => 'string',
        'format'            => 'date-time',
        'validate_callback' => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
    );
```

The parameter available is `modified_after` and in `orderby` the parameter is  `date`

```
    $params['orderby']         = array(
        'description'       => __( 'Sort collection by object attribute.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'              => 'string',
        'default'           => 'date',
        'enum'              => array(
            'date',
            'id',
            'include',
            'title',
            'slug',
            'modified',
        ),
        'validate_callback' => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
    );
```